# combination of coverage and profiler?

Tags: python, profiling, code-coverage

I really like the python coverage module:

```
http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/
```

and the HTML pages it generates. Is there a combination of this and profiling so that one could see a unified HTML report of coverage+profiling.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, for coverage I can't really comment. That tool should do the job. For performance, I make a pest of myself by telling people what works, that might be found unusual: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks, reckoner, glad that you like the HTML output from coverage.  I've never done anything to combine it with a profiler, and haven't heard of anyone else doing it either.

When I created the HTML output, I had in the back of my mind the idea of having it be a generalized source-code-with-tool-annotations facility, but it was enough work just getting it built only for coverage!

Comment: there is a line profiler here:http://packages.python.org/line_profiler/ that annotates individual lines based on profiler info.